# How to get exact message sent to LLM using LangChain's LLMChain (python)?

Tags: python, langchain, py-langchain

Currently, when using an `LLMChain` in LangChain, I can get the template prompt used and the response from the model, but is it possible to get the exact text message sent as query to the model, without having to manually do the prompt template filling?

An example:

```py
from langchain.llms import OpenAI
from langchain.prompts import PromptTemplate
from langchain.chains import LLMChain

llm = OpenAI(model_name="gpt-3.5-turbo-0613")
prompt = PromptTemplate(input_variables=["a", "b"], template="Hello {a} and {b}")
chain = LLMChain(llm=llm, prompt=prompt)
result = chain.call({"a": "some text", "b": "some other text"})
```

I cannot find something like I am looking for in the `chain` or `result` objects. I tried some options such as `return_final_only=True` and `include_run_info=True` but they don't include what I am looking for.

Answer (score 4):

pass `verbose=True` to LLMChain constructor

```py
chain = LLMChain(prompt=..., llm=..., verbose=True)
```

but the problems is that it just prints thru stdout.

i'm also finding how to get exact used prompt string

Answer (score 1):

Here is the way to see that:

```
LLMChain(prompt=prompt,llm=llm).prompt.format_prompt(your_prompt_variables_here).to_string()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: That gets a string that should be similar to the one sent to the model, but, how could I be sure that _that_ was the text sent in the API call?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `.format()` method of `ChatPromptTemplate`, but should work with any `BaseChatPromptTemplate` class.

I struggled to find this as well. In my case I wanted the final formatted prompt string being used inside of the API call.

**Example usage:**

```py
# Define a partial variable for the chatbot to use
my_partial_variable = """APPLE SAUCE"""

# Initialize your chat template with partial variables
prompt_messages = [
    # System message
    SystemMessage(content=("""You are a hungry, hungry bot""")),
    # Instructions for the chatbot to set context and actions
    HumanMessagePromptTemplate(
        prompt=PromptTemplate(
            template="""Your life goal is to search for some {conversation_topic}. If you encounter food in the conversation below, please eat it:\n###\n{conversation}\n###\nHere is the food: {my_partial_variable}""",
            input_variables=["conversation_topic", "conversation"],
            partial_variables={"my_partial_variable": my_partial_variable},
        )
    ),
    # Placeholder for additional agent notes
    MessagesPlaceholder("agent_scratchpad"),
]

prompt = ChatPromptTemplate(messages=prompt_messages)
prompt_as_string = prompt.format(
    conversation_topic="Delicious food",
    conversation="Nothing about food to see here",
    agent_scratchpad=[],
)
```

```py
print(prompt_as_string)
```

```
System: You are a hungry, hungry bot
Human: Your life goal is to search for some Delicious food. If you encounter food in the conversation below, please eat it:
###
Nothing about food to see here
###
Here is the food: APPLE SAUCE
```

(I was using OpenAI + Langchain Agent in my case but the same applies for any ChatPromptTemplate)